# Name/Edit/Remove Manjaro i3 Desktop Elements

Tags: manjaro, desktop, conky

[image]

I have been trying to find the names of these two elements so I can edit/remove them. However, I have failed. What widgets(?) are these and where are their config files? And what placed them on the desktop?

EDIT: Thank you, for naming these, [jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan). After spending some more time with google, I ran 'locate conky' and was able to find `/usr/share/doc/conky-1.10.6_pre/conky.conf` & `./conky_no_x11.conf`. And because they are in `/doc/` I'm thinking they are examples? I can not locate any other `conky.conf` files.

The end goal is to merge the two into the bottom left instance, so my less-used (and easy to forget) $mod combinations are listed along with the computer RAM (shown as used/free).

Comment: They are conky instances.

Comment: Conky config files are usually hidden files in the user's `$HOME` directory with names like `.conky.conf` or something similar. Try `ls -a` in a fresh terminal to see them.

Comment: @Mioriin, no such files found in `/home/me` or `/home/me/.config/` which according to [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Conky) is where the file should live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default session of Manjaro 17 (i3 edition) is using the files in `/usr/share/conky/`.

Pick the ones you want to use and copy them to `/home/user/(.config)`, then edit the options for conky's startup in i3's settings to use those instead.

Now you can edit the new config files to suit your needs.

Comment: Do I need to rename these files from say `conky_grey` to `conky_grey.conf`?

Comment: You can rename them to anything you want. Just remember to point the conky startup in i3 to the new files. ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is managed from the i3 config

```
$ grep conky ~/.i3/config 
exec --no-startup-id start_conky_maia
# exec --no-startup-id start_conky_green
$ which start_conky_maia 
/usr/bin/start_conky_maia
```

So to change how the conky starts in Manjaro i3 Desktop.Either comment out the lines in `~/.i3/config`, or copy the above scripts and edit to your hearts content.

In my case, I have added ~/bin to my $PATH so I can do the following.

```
$ cp /usr/bin/start_conky_maia ~/bin/start_conky_custom 

$ cat ~/bin/start_conky_custom 
#!/bin/bash

# conky -c /usr/share/conky/conky1.10_shortcuts_maia &&
# conky -c /usr/share/conky/conky_maia &&
conky -c  /usr/share/conky/conky_green &&

exit 0

$ grep conky ~/.i3/config 
# exec --no-startup-id start_conky_maia
exec --no-startup-id start_conky_custom
```

Reload, restart i3.